# Empty iceberg table created with PyIceberg in AWS Glue misses location and schema

Tags: python, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I want to create an empty [Iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/) table with [PyIceberg](https://py.iceberg.apache.org/) in AWS Glue.
The snippet below creates the table, but does not show the location and schema information in AWS Glue. What am I missing?

[image: missing s3 location]

[image: missing schema]

```py
from pyiceberg.catalog import load_catalog
from pyiceberg.schema import Schema
from pyiceberg.types import TimestampType, StringType, NestedField

schema = Schema(
    NestedField(field_id=1, name="datetime", field_type=TimestampType()),
    NestedField(field_id=2, name="job_id", field_type=StringType()),
    NestedField(field_id=3, name="result", field_type=StringType()),
    NestedField(field_id=4, name="description", field_type=StringType()),
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    catalog = load_catalog(
        "default",
        **{
            "type": "glue",
        },
    )

    catalog.create_table(
        identifier=f"manually_created.my_test_table",
        schema=schema,
        location="s3://my_test_bucket/my_test_table",
    )
```

with version `pyiceberg==0.5.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is fixed in a newer pyiceberg version (`> 0.5.1`), see [this PR](https://github.com/apache/iceberg-python/pull/288) as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/apache/iceberg-python/issues/435).

`pip install pyiceberg==0.6.0rc4` and location and schema appear.

[image]